# Spring Custom Validator - Interpolate message with parameter

Tags: java, spring, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I've created a custom `ConstraintValidator` where the `isValid` method looks like this:

```
private String message;

@Override
public void initialize(InputValidator constraintAnnotation) {
    this.message = constraintAnnotation.message();
}

@Override
public boolean isValid(String inputValue, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    HibernateConstraintValidatorContext h = context.unwrap(HibernateConstraintValidatorContext.class);
    h.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();

    //logic goes here

    if(!valid) {
        h.addExpressionVariable("0", inputValue);
        h.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate(this.message)
            .addConstraintViolation();
    }
    return valid;
}
```

I also have the following in `messages.properties`:

```
error.input=The value {0} is invalid.
```

I can use the above message and substitute the `{0}` value within when using it within thymeleaf and with a `MessageSource` bean, however the HibernateConstraintValidatorContext will not substitute the value.

Given the constraints of my project I cannot change the message format e.g. changing it to `The value ${0} is invalid.`.

I currently have the application showing the response "The value userInput is invalid." where "userInput" is the name of the field in the form/object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So `{0}` is a message parameter while `${0}` is an expression variable.

You have to use `#addMessageParameter()` instead of `#addExpressionVariable()`. It was introduced in Hibernate Validator 5.4.1 but you should upgrade anyway if you use an older version.